# How to create a truststore from a public RSA key

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, keystore, truststore

I need to read an encrypted ID token in an OpenID Connect flow with a private and public key. Don't need a cert.

First I ran:

openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout key.pem -pubkey -out pubreq.pem -subj "/CN=MyKey"

Got the public and private keys.

Then I ran:

openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey key.pem -out encryptedprivatekeytest.p12 -nocerts

So far so good. The file encryptedprivatekeytest.p12 contains the private key. Now I just need to create a jks truststore file from the public key in pubreq.pem.

Literally no matter how hard I try to find out how to, I just can't.

Any takers?

Answer (score 0):

You have actually created a certificate signing request with the above command.

To generate just a public-private key pair, you can use:

```
openssl genrsa -out private.key 2048
openssl rsa -in private.key -pubout -out public.key
```

However, a trust store contains certificates, not public keys.